# Proving equivalence to the infinity norm

Tags: analysis

I did the proof of $||.||_2$ equivalent to $||.||_\inf$ on my own and understood the concept of finding a constant by squaring both sides. But now I need to solve a question that asks to prove $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ is equivalent to the infinity norm and I’m stuck on how to find the two constants?

Could anyone offer some clues? Thanks.

Comment: Where are these norm defined? What are $n$ and $m$?

Comment: I believe by $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ they mean the map between $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and  $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. And the question really didn’t specify where they are defined so I guess any finite dimensional space?

Comment: One talks about equivalence of two norms when they are defined on the same space. Perhaps, OP is considering $\|. \|_2$ and $\|.\|_{\infty}$ on the space of $n \times m$ matrices.

Comment: Yea sorry I’m pretty new to these concepts and since the exercise did not specify, I’m not sure under what conditions would the exercise be meaningful.